# Extract extra output from server section in Shiny (the app format is a consumer survey to identify segment, from fishers linear functions)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to add an extra line of text to my output. It's from the server area but I'm not sure where I can put it or if it's even right. After selecting all the boxes, the server part runs a calculation using linear functions to find segment classification. I've found the segment, and then sent that text to print to output. I'd also like to use the segment number again, to reference another piece of information, and send that to the output too. This is my code:

```
library(shiny)

df_model <- structure(list(Variable = c("Att1", "Att2", "Att3", "Att4", "Att5", 
                            "Att6", "Constant"), Label = c("I know the latest trends before most of my friends", 
                                                           "I prefer to buy from brands which have a social and environmental commitment", 
                                                           "I am actively involved in local community issues", "I recycle as much of my rubbish as possible", 
                                                           "I like other people to approve of the brands I buy", "I have changed/I am changing my diet to eat fewer animal products/more plant-based foods", 
                                                           "Constant"), Segment_1 = c(1.72935472180569, 1.82253799016844, 
                                                                                      1.29428927223515, 5.3842749985121, 1.34690831129391, 1.11950206453286, 
                                                                                      -51.7073642953413), Segment_2 = c(2.62350386445255, 1.70963698351378, 
                                                                                                                        0.895136129591016, 4.8425343260973, 2.21326348141188, 1.19671650459409, 
                                                                                                                        -49.9792171908105), Segment_3 = c(1.93234156202449, 2.62198119973183, 
                                                                                                                                                          1.11571544436304, 5.12474145547635, 1.41830829677651, 1.94289965965182, 
                                                                                                                                                          -57.0245210302115)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "tbl", "data.frame"))
df_description <- structure(list(Segment_Variable = c("Segment_1", "Segment_2", 
                                    "Segment_3"), Segment_Name = c("Anxious Traditionals", "Self-assured Leaders", 
                                                                   "Positive Active Coasters"), Segment_Description = c("Traditional, patriotic, laid-back, friendly,non-techy, not image conscious, comfort-led, anxious about technology, pessimistic about the future", 
                                                                                                                        "Always seeking entertaining media, tries new products, sociable, self-assured, calm, financially astute", 
                                                                                                                        "Traditional, patriotic, laid-back, friendly,happy with social life,spontaneity,positive"
                                                                   )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                   ))
n_attitudes <- nrow(df_model)-1
attitude_options <- c("Strongly agree"=5 ,"Tend to agree"=4, "Neutral"=3, "Tend to disagree"=2, "Strongly disagree"=1)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Consumer Lifestyle Survey"),
  sidebarLayout(
    helpText("Please can you answer the following statements"),
    mainPanel( 
      br(),
      lapply(1:n_attitudes, function(i) {
        radioButtons( df_model[ i , 1 ] , label = df_model[ i , 2 ], attitude_options, inline=T, selected=character(0) )
      }),
      br(),
      h2( textOutput("product") ),
      h2( textOutput("profile") ),
      br(),
      br(),
      
    ),
  ),
)

# ?radioButtons
# ?textOutput

# Define server logic for slider examples ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$product <- renderText({
    
    responses_n <- as.numeric( c( input$Att1,input$Att2,input$Att3,input$Att4,input$Att5,
                                  input$Att6,input$Att7,input$Att8,input$Att9,input$Att10 ) ) 
    
    if( length(  responses_n )== n_attitudes ) {
      
      responses <- as.numeric( c( input$Att1,input$Att2,input$Att3,input$Att4,input$Att5,
                                  input$Att6,input$Att7,input$Att8,input$Att9,input$Att10 ) )
      
      func1 <- sum(  unname(unlist(df_model[ ,"Segment_1"] ))*c(responses,1) )
      func2 <- sum(  unname(unlist(df_model[ ,"Segment_2"] ))*c(responses,1) )
      func3 <- sum(  unname(unlist(df_model[ ,"Segment_3"] ))*c(responses,1) )

      funcscores <- c(func1,func2,func3)
      funcscores
      
      segment_type <- which.max(  funcscores )
      segment_type
      
      print( paste0('You belong to the segment "', df_description[ segment_type , 2],'"'   ) )
      
    } else {
      
      print("Please answer all statements")   
      
    }
    
  })
  
  output$profile <- renderText({
    print( paste0('Character traits : "', df_description[ segment_type , 3],'"'   ) )
        })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm not sure how to get the **output$profile** part to the UI part, without repeat running the whole fishers functions again which seems inefficient. The context of the work is to ask questions to users so they can find out their consumer segment, one line says what their segment is and the extra line is to explain the characteristics of that segment (this is a shortened version to provide an example). I'm very new to R Shiny, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code chunk for generating `output$profile` (by calling `renderText()`), you make it depends on the variable `segment_type`, which is calculated in another code chunk (which `output$product` is calculated).

Shiny solve this by using so-called "reactivity", which in your case looks like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # init a reactive value
  rv_segment_type <- reactiveValues(st = NULL)
  
  output$product <- renderText({
    
    responses_n <- as.numeric( c( input$Att1,input$Att2,input$Att3,input$Att4,input$Att5,
                                  input$Att6,input$Att7,input$Att8,input$Att9,input$Att10 ) ) 
    
    if( length(  responses_n )== n_attitudes ) {
      
      responses <- as.numeric( c( input$Att1,input$Att2,input$Att3,input$Att4,input$Att5,
                                  input$Att6,input$Att7,input$Att8,input$Att9,input$Att10 ) )
      
      func1 <- sum(  unname(unlist(df_model[ ,"Segment_1"] ))*c(responses,1) )
      func2 <- sum(  unname(unlist(df_model[ ,"Segment_2"] ))*c(responses,1) )
      func3 <- sum(  unname(unlist(df_model[ ,"Segment_3"] ))*c(responses,1) )
      
      funcscores <- c(func1,func2,func3)
      funcscores
      
      segment_type <- which.max(  funcscores )
      segment_type
      rv_segment_type$st <- segment_type  # change the reactive value
      
      print( paste0('You belong to the segment "', df_description[ segment_type , 2],'"'   ) )
      
    } else {
      
      print("Please answer all statements")   
      
    }
    
  })
  
  output$profile <- renderText({
    # use reactive value in another reactive chunk
    # req() makes this chunk depend on a truthy value of rv_segment_type$st to work
    req(rv_segment_type$st)  
    print( paste0('Character traits : "', df_description[ rv_segment_type$st , 3],'"'   ) )
  })
  
}
```

More reading of [the 3rd chapter of Mastering shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html), and you may gain more knowledge about mechanism of shiny's reactivity.

Comment: Amazing thank you! Yes I'm working on this project using the rstudio shiny site to learn from. I've also only started looking at mastering shiny. Not up to chapter 3 yet, a lot to get through. Many thanks,